# How to contain a while loop in a variable

Tags: php, variables

I have the following code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['indexSearchSubmit']))
{
foreach($_POST['industryList'] as $selected)
    {
        $_POST['industryList'] = $selected;
        $locationListResults = $_POST['locationList'];

        $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM currentListings WHERE     location = '$locationListResults' AND industry = '$selected'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
            {
                echo $row['industry'];
                echo $row['location'];
                echo $row['title'];
                echo $row['description'];
            }
    }
                mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Could anyone tell me how I would go about storing the echo part into a variable so I can then display it as and where I want in other parts of the site?

If I remove the echo and instead store `$row` as a variable when I echo that variable it only outputs once and doesn't run the loop.

Comment: I would suggest json as you want to use it this way

Comment: You're SQL injecting yourself to the point where anyone could print out all of your listings very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) for this. The result will be an array where each element is a row and each row is an associative array with the same keys as row in your example

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
$data[0]["industry"]; //Data in the first row
```

You can then loop over `$data` to output it any place on your page.

Comment: how would i then loop over the data?

Comment: Just do a standard foreach loop.

Comment: any change i can get a up vote as i can no longer post questions

Answer (score 0):

put in array,

```
        $list = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
           $list[] = $row;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the values in an array

```
 $rows = array(); 
 $x = 0;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $rows[$x]['industry'] = $row['industry'];
                $rows[$x]['location'] =  $row['location'];
                $rows[$x]['title'] =  $row['title'];
                $rows[$x]['description'] =  $row['description'];
                $x++;
            }
 return $rows;
```

Then you can use $rows as an array.

```
foreach($rows as $v){
  echo $v['industry']." ".$v['location']."<br />";
  echo $v['title']." ".$v['description']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I used your method but now when i echo $rows[1] it should show all results but is only showing one so i guess im doing something wrong for it not to loop any ideas why?

Comment: any change i can get a up vote as i can no longer post questions

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
$arrayList = array();

while($row = mysqli_featch_array($results)){
     $arrayList[] = $row;               
}

print_r($arrayList);
```